# What are examples of high-volume websites with fixed, proportional, fluid, and hybrid layouts?

Tags: css, website-design, website-features, standards, research

For example, [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/) I believe would be an example of a hybrid-fluid-fixed.

Really have no idea what an example of a purely proportional layout would be.

---

**Types of Webpage Layouts** are, per Wikipedia's [Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_design#Layout_types) page:

- **Fixed layout:** Pixel measure results in fixed or static content
- **Proportional layout:** Em measure results in proportional content that is relative to font-size
- **Fluid layout:** Percent measure results in fluid content that shrinks and grows to "fit" display windows
- **Hybrid layout:** Incorporates any combination of fixed, proportional or fluid elements within (or pointing to) a single page.

Comment: **@close(1):** If you're going to vote to close, comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/) as a hybrid example. It is fixed to an extent but observe what happens to the ads on the right hand side of the page as you resize your window.

I would see google as a static example. I am not too sure though.

Also, I believe most high volume sites today are either hybrid or static; I find it hard to find a completely fluid or proportional high volume site, I could be wrong however.

Comment: **@user2686:** Yes, I agree about how few high volume sites are completely fluid or proportional, which makes me wonder why there are even layout types called fluid or proportional.

Comment: **@user2686:** Not sure what to make of the way nettuts wraps the ADs, guess the average user is not playing around with there screen size, but still... just guessing the single column is better at placing a value on the AD unit spaces. The two column one seems a little chaotic value wise.

Comment: @blunders: I believe what nettuts did was merely to show off the mastery/amount of control they have over their css/skills. One need only look at 'fb' at different screen sizes to realize the same thing. Nettuts places a value on the two column AD unit spaces as well as it does on the single column spaces, wrapping and showing their mastery once again. I stand to be corrected.

Comment: **@Black Flames:** Not following you, read what you wrote 3 times, still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @blunders: (sorry, I am still new to the site, experimenting with my username as well) what I was basically saying is that nettuts was merely showing off their mastery/skill in css/layouts (with the double and single column adjusting as well as changing integrated twitter apps depending on the screen size) as do facebook and a few other major sites out there.